GitHub PR only me can see Code Review, and no one else
The problem I noticed that no one except the GitHub repo owner (me) can see a code review.
Example PRs:

1
2

On the first screenshot is what I can see (the PR review started), and next (second screenshot) I created an private window (without GitHub account) then I can't see the PR review, I also tried to do that with people which has specific permissions for example Admin in the organization, but still they can't see it.


To fix it I tried to find a solution to this problem in google and etc, play with Branch Rules, Moderation Settings of the Organization, and users permissions, but no success.

You didn't submit your review, it's still marked "pending".

Oh god LOL! Thank you so much XDDDD

Definitely happened to me, too, in the past
